# Differentiating the string with double quotes from string without double quotes using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file with several lines as follows:

```
    <Property authority="Design" name="X">2538.0</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="Y">-226.084564</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="Z">393.511932</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="Diameter2">0.0</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="AssemblyID">WDLX6B-S11135-Y</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="AssemblyRev">55</Property>
```

I need to search/match "Y" ( line No: 2) only to extract the value. I have written following lines.

```
    for line in file:
        if re.findall("\\bY\\b", line):

            y_cor = re.findall('[-\d]+\.\d*',line)
            print (line)
            print(y_cor)
```

With this, the code is picking the line No.2 as well as line No.5  which also has Y in the line. The output is as follows:

```
    <Property authority="Design" name="Y">-226.084564</Property>

     ['-226.084564']
    <Property authority="Design" name="AssemblyID">WDLX6B-S11135-Y</Property>
     []
```

I need only line no. 2 to be picked. I have already tried following regex.

```
    if re.findall(r' \\"Y\\" ',line):
```

But it is wrong syntax. Can anyone suggest me how to differentiate "Y" from Y? There might be other ways to avoid the line No. 5 to be picked. But i need to make generalised code for X, Y & Z, so that only corresponding lines will be picked. thanks.

Comment: use `lxml` module to parse xml properly, or you'll have problems. regexes are not made to parse xml.

Comment: Why am i getting negative review for this question?

Comment: because it's a bad idea to parse xml with regex. Use the right tools. And in any other form, this is probably a duplicate of some other question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want following output: -226.084564
I can build a simple regex:

```
="Y">(-?[0-9-\.]*)
```

This regex will match only for name="Y". To make it case sensitive I can modify it to `="[Yy]">(-?[0-9-\.]*)`

Output (tested in python):

```
Match 1
1. -226.084564
```

Answer (score 0):

following regex worked for me.

```
    re.findall('\\"Y\\"',line)
```

from now on, I would parse xml with *lxml*.